# WSL2: Python rename files from with VS Code debugger

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-debugging

I'm using WSL2 with a Ubuntu distro with a conda package manager. I can read and edit files on Windows ( accessed via /mnt/c) using the Visual Studio Code GUI (launched by `code .` in the WSL Ubuntu terminal).

I have following script where I'm trying to remove spaces from the name of all pdf files:

```
import os
fldr = '/mnt/c/Documents and Settings/Lenovo/Desktop/'
for f in os.listdir(fldr):
    if 'pdf' in f:
        print(f)
        os.rename(fldr+f, fldr+f.replace(' ','_'))
        print(f.replace(' ','_'))
```

If I run the script via the debugger (F5) I get a permission error [Errno 13]

If I use the terminal created by debugger to manually rename using Python code, I don't get the permission error.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is a difference between the user that runs the debugger (which runs in your windows) and the user that is running inside WSL.

try running the following command to set the username the same as the windows one:

```
wsl --user <your username>
```